# SonarQube JSP Analysis shows false positive "Potential XSS in JSP"

Tags: jsp, sonarqube, findbugs

Using SonarQube for static code analysis of our web application, I recently activate the JSP plugin, too.  The analysis raised issues complaining about unescaped expressions, a correct issue description for the original code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="${pageContext.request.locale}">
```

(complaining about the second line).  The SonarQube rule (findsecbugs-jsp:XSS_JSP_PRINT) gave the following explanation and potential solution:

> Blockquote
>   A potential XSS was found. It could be used to execute unwanted JavaScript in a client's browser. (See references)
>
> Vulnerable Code:
>
> <%
>
> String taintedInput = (String) request.getAttribute("input");
>
> %>
>
> [...]
>
> <%= taintedInput %>
>
> Solution:
>
> <%
>
> String taintedInput = (String) request.getAttribute("input");
>
> %>
>
> [...]
>
> <%= Encode.forHtml(taintedInput) %>
>
> The best defense against XSS is context sensitive output encoding like the example above. There are typically 4 contexts to consider: HTML, JavaScript, CSS (styles), and URLs. Please follow the XSS protection rules defined in the OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet, which explains these defenses in significant detail.

(The findbugs rule can also be found at https://find-sec-bugs.github.io/bugs.htm#XSS_JSP_PRINT).

Although the described situation did not fully match my original code (I used EL, the example used pure JSP), I tried to follow the rule and added OWASP Java Encoder to our project: https://owasp.org/owasp-java-encoder/encoder-jsp/index.html which is one of the references mentioned in the rule.

The resulting code looks like:

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="e" uri="https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="${e:forHtmlAttribute(pageContext.request.locale)}">
```

Which is more or less an exact match of the example on the OWASP taglibs documentation site and seems to do the right thing.

Unfortunalely, after running the SonarQube analysis again, I got exactly the same issue at the same line (this time the new code).

Can somebody tell me what exactly triggers this rule and how code should look like that does not anymore raise the issue?

For the record:  I also used e:forHtml instead of e:forHtmlAttribute, which is closer to the rule but seems to be less a fit in the circumstances.  Even e:forHtml left the issue open.

I'm using SonarQube Community EditionVersion 7.9.1 (build 27448) with the BuiltIn FindBugs security JSP plugin.

Thanks a lot in advance for any hints.

edit:  It seems that without using the taglib I can have findbugs the escaping reckognized.  This works and does not raise the issue anymore, however I regard it ugly:

```html
<%@ page import="org.owasp.encoder.Encode" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<%Encode.forHtmlAttribute("${pageContext.request.locale}");%>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea here: Maybe this happens because it identified rendered HTML content directly from user input, even though you correctly escape it. Could you do this in two steps?

1. Set a new variable for the content of
   `e:forHtmlAttribute(pageContext.request.locale)`
2. Use the new variable in your `<html lang=` content

Cheers!

Comment: How could I accomplish this?  Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with JSPs so I may be terribly wrong, but my impression is that the variable would be set inside a <%-tag, which would leave me using the class directly instead of the taglib.